# Report for unique accounts with activities

Tags: reporting

I added a field to my activities that depicts the customer sentiment after the call.
I'm trying to build a report that will count unique Accounts that have activities with positive sentiment, but I get the count of positive activities instead.
Can anyone suggest how to achieve the desired count?

Comment: Search for "salesforce power of one" - SteveMo has demoed this on the Answers board.